# What is the lifetime of the various types of Angular module?

Tags: angular

What is the lifetime of the various types of Angular module, and what are their setup/teardown semantics, assuming they are ever destroyed.

This would be particularly useful to know for lazy loaded feature modules, since they have scoped services which the Angular documentation states are destroyed when the module is destroyed, but I can find nothing whatsoever in the Angular documentation that describes when any modules are ever destroyed.

Comment: Does this documentation answer your question(s)? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: No, because that doesn't mention modules at all and is about component lifecycle.

Comment: I do wish people wouldn't vote to close questions just because they don't understand the question.

Comment: If you are talking strictly about a module it does not get loaded into memory. It is a way to group component/services/etc that are logically related. Those items are then included in the final produced .js file bundles. The closest you can come to loading a module would be [lazy module loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules). This is more specific to downloading over the network than loading anything specific into memory (an example of the later would be creating a component instance).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/providers#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances "When Angular destroys an NgModule or component instance, it also destroys that injector and that injector's service instances" This indicates modules have lifetime that (in the case of lazy loaded modules) control the lifetime of service instances created via their injector. If that's the case I need to know how that lifetime works, if that's not the case then the documentation is seriously misleading.